# Check if repeating Key or Value exists in Python Dictionary

Tags: python, python-2.7, list, dictionary, distinct-values

The following is my dictionary and I need to check if I have repeated key or Value

```
dict = {' 1': 'a', '2': 'b', '3': 'b', '4': 'c', '5': 'd', '5': 'e'}
```

This should return false or some kind of indicator which helps me print out that key or value might be repeated. It would be much appreciated if I am able to identify if a key is repeated or a Value (but not required).

Comment: All of the below solutions work, I am marking the one I used.
The solutions below gave me kinds of exposure

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Dictionaries can't have duplicate keys, so in case of repeated keys it only keeps the last value, so check values (one-liner is your friend):

```
print(('There are duplicates' if len(set(dict.values()))!=len(values) else 'No duplicates'))
```

Answer (score 3):

Well in a dictionary keys can't repeat so we only have to deal with values.

```
dict = {...}

# get the values
values = list(dict.values())
```

And then you can use a `set()` to check for duplicates:

```
if len(values) == len(set(values)): print("no duplicates")
else: print("duplicates)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to check if a key repeats in a dictionary, because dictionaries in Python only support unique keys. If you enter the dictionary as is, only the last value will be associated with the redundant key:

```
In [4]: dict = {' 1': 'a', '2': 'b', '3': 'b', '4': 'c', '5': 'd', '5': 'e'}

In [5]: dict
Out[5]: {' 1': 'a', '2': 'b', '3': 'b', '4': 'c', '5': 'e'}
```

Answer (score 0):

A one-liner to find repeating values

```
In [138]: {v: [k for k in d if d[k] == v] for v in set(d.values())}
Out[138]: {'a': [' 1'], 'b': ['2', '3'], 'c': ['4'], 'e': ['5']}
```

Check all the unique values of the `dict` with `set(d.values())` and then creating a list of keys that correspond to those values.

Note: repeating keys will just be overwritten

```
In [139]: {'a': 1, 'a': 2}
Out[139]: {'a': 2}
```

Answer (score 0):

What about

```
has_dupes = len(d) != len(set(d.values()))
```

I'm on my phone so I cant test it. But j think it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Well, although key value should be unique according to the documentation, there is still condition where repeated key could appear.

For example,

```
>>> import json
>>> a = {1:10, "1":20}
>>> b = json.dumps(a)
>>> b
'{"1": 20, "1": 10}'
>>> c = json.loads(b)
>>> c
{u'1': 10}
>>>
```

But in general, when python finds out there's conflict, it takes the latest value assigned to that key.

For your question, you should use comparison such as

```
len(dict) == len(set(dict.values()))
```

because set in python contains an unordered collection of **unique** and **immutable** objects, it could automatically get all unique values even when you have duplicate values in `dict.values()`